# Prepositions for vs to

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, difference

**For** and **to** are both confusing prepositions in English. Please help me in the following sentence:

> 1. It will be fun for you.
> 2. It will be fun to you.

Do both sentences have the meaning or not?

When should either sentence be used?

Answer (score 1):

The normal preposition is *fun **for** someone*, so the short answer is OP's example #1 is correct, and #2 is "invalid".

But as an illustration of a *potential* distinction in similar contexts,...

> 1: *This isn't fun **for** me*
>    normally implies
>    *This isn't entertaining me / I'm not enjoying it*

BUT...

> 2: *This isn't fun **to** me*
>     might tend to imply
>    *This isn't the kind of thing I would call "fun"*

In that second case, maybe the speaker himself isn't even participating (he's just offering an *opinion*). But it's important to note that the (relatively small) difference in meaning isn't inherently conveyed by the specific preposition ***to*** as such. It's more that the average native speaker *expects* ***for***, so when he hears ***to*** he has to think of some slight difference in nuance that could reasonably apply.

---

Also note that whereas in the specific examples above, any difference in meaning is both small *and* not universally recognised, there's a clear-cut distinction if we switch to...

> 3: *He is good **for** me*
>    4: *He is good **to** me*

...where #3 means *Being with him **improves** me as a person* (perhaps he even treats me harshly, but that's good for me because I need to learn discipline). But #4 means *He's **generous** to me / treats me well*. And all native speakers would recognise *that* distinction - there's no hint of "non-standard preposition must imply non-standard meaning" there - both usages are completely "standard", with well-known different meanings.